# angularJS carousel negative cycling with modulo operation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a carousel component using AngularJS following [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dgL5P/) I found on stackoverflow.

The next function works as expected, but when I tried to do the same for the previous function, it goes into negative value when it hits 0, cycles until -3, then jumps back to 0.

Can somebody please explain what `% $scope.pages.length` does exactly, and how it works? I tried googling, but found no explanations.

my controller:

```
.controller('portfolioController', function($scope) {
    $scope.pages = [
    {
        image: "/../images/Placeholder.jpg",
        alt: "thumbnail first page",
        name : "1",
        description : "Moj Prvi Webpage",
        active : 1
    },
    {
        image: "/../images/Placeholder.jpg",
        alt: "thumbnail first page",
        name : "2",
        description : "Moj Drugi Webpage",
        active : 0
    },
    {
        image: "/../images/Placeholder.jpg",
        alt: "thumbnail first page",
        name : "3",
        description : "Moj Tretji Webpage",
        active : 0
    },
    {
        image: "/../images/Placeholder.jpg",
        alt: "thumbnail first page",
        name : "4",
        description : "Moj Četrti Webpage",
        active : 0
    }
    ];
    $scope.current = 0;
    $scope.Next = function() {
        $scope.current = ($scope.current + 1) % $scope.pages.length;
    }
    $scope.Previous = function() {
        $scope.current = ($scope.current - 1) % $scope.pages.length;
    }
});
```

my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img ng-src="{{ pages[current].image }}" alt="{{ pages[current].alt }}">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ pages[current].name }}</h3>
                <p>{{ pages[current].description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row carousel-thumbnails">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Previous()">Previous</div>
                <img ng-repeat="img in pages" ng-class="{'active': img.active}" src="{{ img.image }}" alt="{{ img.alt }}">              
                <div class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Next()">Next</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question is a [modulo (or remainder) operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()). It takes the first value, divides it by the second value, and returns the remainder.

The reason your `$scope.Previous` isn't working is because it will start returning negative numbers once it reaches zero instead of going back to the max value (in this case that value would be `$scope.pages.length - 1`. To avoid this, try something like this (where the question mark is the [ternary/conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
$scope.current = $scope.current == 0 ? ($scope.pages.length - 1) : ($scope.current - 1)
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgL5P/1/)